# Block missing exception while processing the data from hdfs in spark standalone cluster

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I Was running the spark on the hadoop with 2 workers and 2 datanodes .
First machine contains : sparkmaster , namenode , worker-1 , datanode-1.
Second machine contains : worker2, datanode2

In hadoop cluster there are 2 files under the **/usr** directory on datanode-1 : Notice.txt and on datanode-2 : README.txt

I want to create a rdd from these two file and make a count of lines.

on the first machine I ran spark shell with master **spark://masterIP:7077 [Standalone mode]**

Then on the scala command line created RDD with 
val rdd = sc.textFile("/usr/")
but when i went for the count operation **rdd.count()** it throws following error

```
(TID 2, masterIP, executor 1): org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block: BP-1313298757-masterIP-1499412323227:blk_1073741827_1003 file=/usr/README.txt
```

worker-1 is picking the **NOTICE.txt** but worker-2 is not picking **README.txt**

I was not getting the problem, any help will be appreciated , Thanks

Comment: Looks like your node is not able to find the hdfs block. Can you try 'hadoop fsck "filename"' on the file?

Comment: It gave me following output :   Total size:    16344 B
 Total dirs:    1
 Total files:   2
 Total symlinks:                0
 Total blocks (validated):      2 (avg. block size 8172 B)

Comment: I am confused whether missing in spark configuration or hadoop configuration , At my namenode and spark master its showing me the proper datanodes and workers respecttively.